# RS: Year and Month filter - Highlight line

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, filter, expression, highlight

I want to highlight all months that are older than current month. 
By creating a expression in Reporting Services. 
I have this expression for month, which works:

```
=IIF(month(Fields!Date.Value) < month(today()), "Gold", "White")
```

Now I want to add year as a filter just to be safe, not sure how to do this:

```
=IIF(month(Fields!Date.Value) < month(today()), "Gold", "White") & IIF year(Fields!Date.Value) <= year(today())
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IIF(month(Fields!Date.Value) < month(today()) AND year(Fields!Date.Value) <= year(today()), "Gold", "White")
```

this might not be the right way of doing but in the mean time hope this helps

```
=IIF((year(Fields!Date.Value)< year(today())) OR (month(Fields!Date.Value) < month(today()) AND year(Fields!Date.Value) = year(today())), "Gold", "White")
```

There could be a better way if you describe what you want to do

Comment: Thanks, this runs, but...
For Date.Value = November 2011 it does not get highlighted, because of the month filter. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK it works to put each filter like in the second expression.
Is there a way to find the time for "yearmonth()"?
Instead of doing the year() and then month().

Comment: `Fields!Date.Value <= today()` didn't work for you? or `Fields!Date.Value <= DateTime.Today`

Comment: No, because it has to be the previous month when looking at today()